# Magento 2 EE : Override Layered Navigation Template

Tags: magento-enterprise, template, overrides, layered-navigation, magento2.2.2

I want to override layered navigation template in my module(layer/view.phtml).

I created **`catalog_category_view_type_layered.xml`** file in **`Companyname/Modulename/view/frontend/layout/`**

> catalog_category_view_type_layered.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="catalog.leftnav">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Companyname_Modulename::view.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceBlock name="category.products">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Companyname_Modulename::products.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Above file works proper in community edition but not working in enterprise edition.

Comment: I think there is a problem with set template, move your phtml into "layer/view.phtml".

Comment: If your file is already there then set "<argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Companyname_Modulename::layer/view.phtml</argument>"